# Prove $\exp(f_n(B_{T_{n+1}}-B_{T_n}))\in{L}^1({{\Omega},\mathcal{F}_{T_{n+1}},P})$

Tags: stochastic-processes, expected-value, conditional-probability, brownian-motion, conditional-expectation

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},(\mathcal{F}_t:t\ge{0}),P)$ be a stochastic basis, $B=(B_t:t\ge{0})$ the Brownian Motion and $\forall{n=1,\dots,{N}}$ we have $f_n\in{L}^\infty({{\Omega},\mathcal{F}_n,P})$. I need to show that:
$$\prod_{n=1}^N{\exp[f_n\cdot(B_{T_{n+1}}-B_{T_n})]}\in{L}^1({{\Omega},\mathcal{F}_{T_{N+1}},P}),$$
which means:
$$\mathbb{E}\{\prod_{n=1}^N{\exp[f_n\cdot(B_{T_{n+1}}-B_{T_n})]}\}<\infty.$$

I think I should use the tower property, conditioning to $\mathcal{F}_{T_{n+1}}$, combined  with the "taking out what is known" property; but this require at least that $\forall{n=1,...,N}$ we have:
$$\exp(f_n(B_{T_{n+1}}-B_{T_n}))\in{L}^1({{\Omega},\mathcal{F}_{T_{n+1}},P}).$$
Since I don't know the distribution of $f_n$, I can't compute the expected value. I even thought about the moment generating function of the normal distribution, but $f_n$ is not a constant. Where can I start from?

Comment: If $f_n \in L^\infty$, then $\prod_{n=1}^N \exp(f_n(B_{T_{n+1}}-B_{T_n})$ is also bounded, so it is automatically in $L^1$

Comment: @user6247850 $f_n\in{L}^\infty$ but $B_{T_n+1}-B_{T_n}$ is not bounded, so how can $f_n(B_{T_{n+1}}-B_{T_n})$ be bounded?

Comment: @geetha290krm if I assume $f_n$ bounded everywhere on $\Omega$, I still don't get how can $f_n(B_{T_{n+1}}-B_{T_n})$ be bounded, considering $B_{T_n}$ is not

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread it.  I thought we had $f_n: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.